# trouble turning this into a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
Declare @YearToGet int
Set @YearToGet = 2008

;With RawData As
    (
    Select 39503 As Booked
    Union All Select 39509
    Union All Select 39535
    Union All Select 39620
    Union All Select 39791
    Union All Select 39838
    Union All Select 39899
    Union All Select 39134
    Union All Select 39139
    Union All Select 39139
    Union All Select 39140
    Union All Select 39146
    Union All Select 39146
    Union All Select 39146
    )
    , Numbers As 
    (
    Select 0 As Value, Year(GetDate()) As [Year]
        , Cast( DateDiff(d,0,GetDate()) as datetime ) As [Date]
        , DateDiff(d,0,GetDate()) As [DateInt]
    Union All 
    Select Value + 1, [Year] - 1
        , DateAdd(yyyy, -1, [Date])
        , DateDiff(d, 0, DateAdd(yyyy, -1, [Date]))
    From Numbers
    Where Value <= ( Year(GetDate()) - @YearToGet )
    )
Select DIVISION, SDESCR, DYYYY
    , SUM(APRICE) AS Sales
    , SUM(PARTY) AS PAX
    , SUM(NetAmount) AS NetSales
    , SUM(InsAmount) AS InsSales
    , SUM(CancelRevenue) AS CXSales
    , SUM(OtherAmount) AS OtherSales
    , SUM(CXVALUE) AS CXValue
From dbo.B101BookingsDetails As BD
    Join Numbers As N
        On Cast(N.[Year] As char(4)) = BD.DYYYY
Where BD.Booked = N.DateInt - 2
Group By DIVISION, SDESCR, DYYYY
```

Comment: this is not a question! please specify what you tried and what/where it went wrong

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyStoredProcedure
 @YearToGet int 
AS

With RawData As 
    ( 
    Select 39503 As Booked 
    Union All Select 39509 
    Union All Select 39535 
    Union All Select 39620 
    Union All Select 39791 
    Union All Select 39838 
    Union All Select 39899 
    Union All Select 39134 
    Union All Select 39139 
    Union All Select 39139 
    Union All Select 39140 
    Union All Select 39146 
    Union All Select 39146 
    Union All Select 39146 
    ) 
    , Numbers As  
    ( 
    Select 0 As Value, Year(GetDate()) As [Year] 
        , Cast( DateDiff(d,0,GetDate()) as datetime ) As [Date] 
        , DateDiff(d,0,GetDate()) As [DateInt] 
    Union All  
    Select Value + 1, [Year] - 1 
        , DateAdd(yyyy, -1, [Date]) 
        , DateDiff(d, 0, DateAdd(yyyy, -1, [Date])) 
    From Numbers 
    Where Value <= ( Year(GetDate()) - @YearToGet ) 
    ) 
Select DIVISION, SDESCR, DYYYY 
    , SUM(APRICE) AS Sales 
    , SUM(PARTY) AS PAX 
    , SUM(NetAmount) AS NetSales 
    , SUM(InsAmount) AS InsSales 
    , SUM(CancelRevenue) AS CXSales 
    , SUM(OtherAmount) AS OtherSales 
    , SUM(CXVALUE) AS CXValue 
From dbo.B101BookingsDetails As BD 
    Join Numbers As N 
        On Cast(N.[Year] As char(4)) = BD.DYYYY 
Where BD.Booked = N.DateInt - 2 
Group By DIVISION, SDESCR, DYYYY 

GO;
```

For further information about creating Stored Procedures, check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) out.

Comment: LOL did you just add a GO?  If so you get a +1 from me...

Comment: Don't forget the CREATE PROCEDURE ;o)